# Displaying information from JSON request

Tags: php, json, youtube-api

For the sake of having you guys being able to read what I'm doing, I will post this with the api key and then edit it after.

How do I display the information from this url?

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=UItqDZuHOsM&key=AIzaSyAQ26GN-removedapikey

I am using this code, but I don't understand the correct way to grab the json stuff. I've tried tons of different ways.

```
$vidkey = $vid_row['youtube_id'];
$apikey = "removed";
$json_output = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=$vidkey&key=$apikey");
$json = json_decode($json_output, true);

//video title
$you_title = $json['snippet']['title'];
```

I guess I don't understand the hierarchy of it all.

Answer (score 0):

Try do to a `print_r($json)` to understand what you're exactly doing. But just navigate in it as an object. In the current case just do:

```
$json['items'][0]['snippet']['title'];
```

But if you want to do it with a more easy way to do it (object way), just remove the true from your `json_decode` function

```
$json->items[0]->snippet->title;
```

Comment: Hey thanks. I get the information when printing, but your "$json->items->snippet->title;" does not work either.

Comment: yea it still doesn't return anything.

Comment: $json = json_decode($json_output, true); i took off the true and it worked... Would you kindly answer as to why? :)

Comment: The second parameter (true) define if you're retrieving an associative array or an object. You could let the true and just use `$json['items'][0]['snippet']['title'];`

Answer (score 0):

**Use Below code to get Title :**

```
$vidkey = $vid_row['youtube_id'];
$apikey = "**********";
$json_output = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=$vidkey&key=$apikey");
$json = json_decode($json_output, true);

echo $json['items'][0]['snippet']['title'];
```

Comment: Thanks bud, you're correct like the other guy. Would you kindly remove my api key though.. my fault lol :)